# Object apartment vs Thread apartment

Tags: c#, c++, com, atl

I read about apartment model, but it is still confusing me when I'm trying to understand the following: whose apartment dictates the apartment model? Is it the thread's apartment or the apartment of the created object?
Consider the following scenario:

1. I've created C++ ATL COM dll that has only one interface which is `ISimpleCom`, and I have a class the implements that interface which has only one method `test();`
   This class publicly inherit from `CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>` which sets STA apartment.
2. Reference this DLL in C# WinForms project, and create the `SimpleCom` object on a MTA thread (not the UI thread).
   The question is:
   Lets say UI thread call `test()` on this object, will it be marshaled to the thread created the object or it will be executed on the UI thread ?

   - If it follows the object COM apartment this call should be marshaled to the thread who created the object because it is an STA object.
   - If it follows creating thread apartment which is MTA, it should be executed on the UI thread.

Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rules:

- A thread might be a member of zero or one apartments
- Single threaded apartments (STA) consist of single thread, MTA - of one or more threads, but there can be at most one MTA per process
- Threads "join" apartments at the time of their COM initialization

So a piece of code is executed either in STA (on STA thread), or in MTA, or the thread is not yet initialized with COM. When you instantiate an object through COM, COM will match apartment model to the type of apartment the API is called from.

> This class publicly inherit from CComObjectRootEx which sets STA apartment.

No. This has nothing to do with setting apartment model. `CComSingleThreadModel` says that this class is using simple base which is good for objects to be run on STA - in particular it will not use InterlockedXxx API or critical sections when it comes to accessing object's reference counter because the class is assumed to live within single thread. This does set apartment model of the COM class, it does not indicate that this class is to be run on STA, this just provides suitable base class.

Apartment model for the ATL COM DLL hosted class will be indicated on .RGS file, associated with the COM class, and will be merged into registry with DLL registration. If this is "Apartment" model then...

> create the SimpleCom object on a MTA thread (not the UI thread).

... COM will see that it cannot instantiate on the calling thread directly, because the thread belongs to MTA. So COM will instantiate on the worker STA thread and will create a proxy/stub pair to marhshal the requested interface into caller MTA.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, from the scenario I've described in my post neither the UI thread nor the MTA thread that created the Class will execute test(). test()'s execution will be marshaled to worker thread on which COM class was created and in which is lives ?

Comment: It won't be executed on MTA thread. The call will be marshaled into worker, or into UI thread if it is STA thread. Then the actual method will be executed from there.

Comment: To avoid confusion lets id the threads: 1-UI , 2-MTA, 3-Worker. So the COM object was created on thread #2 but because it is MTA thread it created new STA worker thread with thread id #3. Now UI thread #1, calls COM's object test() method, from your reply test() will be marshaled to thread #3 and executed by that thread ?

Comment: UI thread can be STA thread, MTA thread, non-COM thread. This is important and defines where COM will assign/instantiate the class, either on #1 UI STA thread, or on #3 Worker STA thread

Comment: In my case com will instantiate on first "available" STA thread ?If so do I have any control on which one ?

Comment: Just instantiate on STA thread you need it at, then marshal into MTA for further use,

Comment: As a C++ programmer, it's often quite feasible to implement your COM classes as "Free Threaded". That means they can run in both STA and MTA, and COM won't bother with proxies. As long as your own code is threadsafe and doesn't inherit apartment restrictions from other COM components, this will work.

Comment: @MSalters: a small correction - it's perhaps rather "Both Threaded". "Free Threaded" is MTA only. "Both" is the apartment threading model. On the other hand an object can embed "free threaded marshaler" which is a special type of marshal implementation that passes interface pointers between apartments in raw form, eliminating proxies. Maybe this is what you were meaning.

Comment: @RomanR.: You're right, I got them confused. I indeed meant "both threaded", when you don't care about the callers apartment.

Comment: In fact, there is a confusion between the registry `ThreadingModel` value and *every other COM-related media*. The registry uses `ThreadingModel="Free"` for MTA, but everything else uses "Free-Threaded" for objects that can run on any apartment and be called directly across apartment boundaryes, and use the Free-Threaded Marshaler to do so (`ThreadingModel="Both"`). This is very sad due to how confusing it is.